# "Screenshot Node" maximum size in Firefox?

Tags: screenshot, nodes

there is a right-click "Screenshot Node" tool in the F12 developer tools in Firefox, but i cant seem to get any screenshot over 7794 pixels in height, so i wonder if the maximum limit can be changed somewhere or what is the limit.

thanks